# Team Explorer не видны кнопки

Tags: git, explorer, team

подскажите пжлст, у меня некорректно отображается Team Explorer: не видны кнопки чтоб слить ветки, создать новую и тд, см вложенные картинки.

Переходил в параметры, там лишь некие глобальные настройки...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте, что написано на скриншоте. "функции перемещены", на кнопки пробовали нажимать? в закладки соответствующие заходили?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, смотри https://www.cyberforum.ru/version-control/thread3010993.html#post16378598

В общем как я понял, в 2022 версии всё поменялось и старые ролики по Гиту не особо актуальны, есть видосы на англ : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zSVvTQXSIc , если нету меню Гит- его можно добавить вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71315500/how-do-i-get-the-git-menu-to-appear-in-visual-studio-2019